# How to delete lines containing the pattern `{.*[a-Z0-9《》【】].*}` with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I need to delete all lines containing any of `a-Z`, `0-9`, or the symbols `《`, `》`, `【`, or `】` from a file, but only if they are found somewhere inside of braces (`{` and `}`), also found on the same line.

E.g., take the sample file:

```
Once {upon} a time, there lived an owl.
The owl lived in a {forest with 10,000 trees.}
One day, the owl said, "I like to eat mice."
So the owl ate {10,000} mice.
The owl said, {“吃饱了！”}
Then{,} the owl rested.
The next day, he read the book, 《水滸傳》.
He enjoyed it so much, that he read {《水滸傳》} again the next day.
```

- Lines 1 and 2 would be deleted, because items with `a-Z` are found somewhere between the braces.
- Lines 4 (and 2 again) would be deleted, because numbers are found somewhere between the braces.
- Line 8 would be deleted, because `《` is present and inside braces.
- The other lines are ignored, because they have neither of these items are placed between the `{` and `}` braces.

I tried making this BASH script, but after checking the output carefully, found some instances when it did not work:

```
sed '/{.*[a-Z0-9《》【】].*}/d' input.txt > output.txt
```

- The braces are never nested.
- The braces are never split across a line.

Why is my `sed` script not properly deleting all of the lines with `a-Z`, `0-9`, `《`, `》`, `【`, or `】` when found between braces?

Comment: I observe immediately that `a-Z` is an invalid regular expression character range (uppercase letters have ordinal values before lowercase letters). Have you tried `A-Za-z` instead? Update: confirming the error `"RE error: invalid character range"` for `a-Z`

Comment: It's also unclear how your `sed` copes with the non-ASCII brackets. If your locale, your input file, and your `sed` implementation are UTF-8 there should be no problem, but that's a big if. So, what character encoding are you using, and does your `sed` support it? If `echo '》' | sed '/》/d'` prints anything at all, this basically cannot work (but you could switch e.g. to Perl to get the job done with almost no changes).

Comment: `echo '》' | sed '/》/d'` prints nothing. I have GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Your character class is incorrect `[a-Z]`. It should be either `[a-z]` or `[A-Z]` or both `[a-zA-Z]`.

```
sed '/{[^}]*[a-zA-Z0-9《》【】][^}]*}/d' file
```

```
$ cat file
Once {upon} a time, there lived an owl.
The owl lived in a {forest with 10,000 trees.}
One day, the owl said, "I like to eat mice."
So the owl ate {10,000} mice.
The owl said, {“吃饱了！”}
Then{,} the owl rested.
The next day, he read the book, 《水滸傳》.
He enjoyed it so much, that he read {《水滸傳》} again the next day.
```

```
$ sed '/{[^}]*[a-zA-Z0-9《》【】][^}]*}/d' file
One day, the owl said, "I like to eat mice."
The owl said, {“吃饱了！”}
Then{,} the owl rested.
The next day, he read the book, 《水滸傳》.
```

Comment: Beware `.*` is greedy and if there is more than one occurence of `{...}` on a line then all characters between the first `{` and last `}` will be included in the match (including those outside of `{...}`). Better to exclude those by changing `.*` to [^}]*`.

Comment: @potong Thanks, yes you are right. However, OP stated that `{..}` are not nested so I left it as is.

Comment: There could be a false positive in `{,} foo {,}` so you should do what @potong said.

Comment: @tripleee Thats a good edge case. I never wanted to disagree with potong. I just took OPs command, fixed the character class and posted the answer. But better to answer correct to avoid another question. `:)`. Will update. Thanks guys!